# Bootstrap Selectpicker data-subtext disappears

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

Been using Bootstrap Selectpicker but when I add data-content to data-subtext to highlight the selection in a colour, the subtext disappears. Tried it various ways but the subtext still disappears from the dropdown list. Any ideas or maybe a workaround?

Forgive the lack of code, I have everything running locally as my slow broadband struggles with with CDN's.

```html
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-light" data-width="100%" multiple data-max-options="2">
<option data-content="<span class='label label-success'>Choice1</span>" data-subtext="Subtext1">Choice1</option>
<option data-content="<span class='label label-info'>Choice2</span>" data-subtext="Subtext2">Choice2</option>
<option data-content="<span class='label label-warning'>Choice3</span>" data-subtext="Subtext3">Choice3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, I have an idea: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach/workaround to do that:

```js
$('select.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

```css
.bootstrap-select .filter-option .text-muted {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-light" data-width="100%" multiple data-max-options="2">
<option data-content="<span class='label label-success'>Choice1 </span> <small class='text-muted'>Subtext1</small>">Choice1</option>
<option data-content="<span class='label label-info'>Choice2 </span><small class='text-muted'>Subtext2</small>">Choice2</option>
<option data-content="<span class='label label-warning'>Choice3 </span><small class='text-muted'>Subtext3</small>">Choice3</option>
</select>
```

Removed of the `data-subtext` attribute and added the same HTML to the `data-content` (it was just a matter of CSS class `text-muted` to be added, for example:

```
<option data-content="<span class='label label-success'>Choice1 </span> <small class='text-muted'>Subtext1</small>">Choice1</option>
```

Added the CSS in order to hide the subtext from the selected options. Try removing that and you'll notice the difference.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

To make multiple selectpickers work based on cloning the elements, instead of adding classes `carerClass` and `carerCopy`, add them as IDs or `data-` attributes and clone them based on that. The issue with adding classes is that `selectpicker` initialization picks up those classes and adds it to the generated bootstrap HTML code which keeps the cloning in a loop and messes up the selection. For more details, check the DOM for the cloned elements in your *non-working* fiddle.

1. Change the classes that you add to either an ID or a data-attribute.
2. First clone the select element, then initiate the selectpicker.

Here's a fork of your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/z7xzt96a/

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I have played with this for days. Didn't think I would ever get a reply. Today I finally got to thinking I should hide the text and only show when the dropdown is showing, but the events were getting the better of me. Still learning but really appreciate your work :-)

Comment: You're welcome. I looked at this question last night and then thought this can be done easily by looking at the HTML used for `subtext`. I, personally, liked this usage (question) and maybe I'll use it in some of my apps. Anyway, glad I could help. Enjoy coding! :)

Comment: It works great, but whenever I clone the code so I can have multiple dropdowns, it only works in the first instance. Basically this dropdown has options which are selected for every hour in a full day, 24 dropdowns in total. Is it a case of making each one unique? Not sure how to do that, probably using JS? Any ideas? If I copy the code each individual dropdown works fine. I'm cloning it to reduce the html, but that's where I get the problem.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle with a couple of clones and reproduce the issue so that I can fork?

Comment: Unique them by ID is what I can suggest just by reading your query! A fiddle would help me understand the problem better.

Comment: after adding it to this fiddle, it seems to work. I think there is something wrong in my html somewhere

Comment: If I copy the working jsfiddle exactly to my pc, I use Adobe brackets, it doesn't work. I just can't get my head round it.

Comment: Thanks for the **non** working fiddle. I got it. I'll edit the main post.

Comment: As I needed multiple copies I went down the obvious classes route instead of ID's. As I wouldn't be able to have multiple ID's with the same name, I'll have to go down the attribute route. Many thanks for your help, greatly appreciated. Now to work out how data- attributes work, haven't used them that much :-)

Comment: It's pretty simple. Just change the `id="carerClass"` to `data-id="carerClass"` and selection in jQuery is done by `$('[data-id="carerClass"]').clone().appendTo('[data-id="carerCopy"]')`. Here are the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)